# Reload a page based on a dropdown list in php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a dropdown list on my page and have a html table on same page and  have  column whose value coming from database table.
Dropdown list have 3 option. i.e. federal,state and local
i want that when i select any option, my page reloads on same page and change the column value in table whose value is set in database for federal_value,state_value and local_value.

```
<select name="election" id="text" >
            <option value="federal"> Federal </option>
            <option value="state"> State </option>
            <option value="local"> Local </option>
          </select>

this is dropdown list code


    <form name="form1">
              <table width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#c0c0c0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="9%" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="head01"><input type="checkbox" value="1" onClick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').attr('checked', this.checked);" id="check_all" name="data[Farm][check_all]" >
                  </td>
                  <td width="7%" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="head01">Sr. No. </td>
                  <td width="25%" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="head01">Leader name</td>
                  <td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="head01">Facebook Like</td>
                  <td width="11%" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="head01">Twitter Like</td>
                  <td width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="head01" id="value"> Value</td>
                  <td width="12%" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="head01">View Profile</td>
                  <td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="head01">Select PM</td>
                </tr>


    <?php
    $election=$_REQUEST['election'];
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leader_info"); 
     $i=1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
          {             
    ?>
                <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><input type="hidden" value="0" id="chkids" name="chkid[0]">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ChkIds" value="<?php echo $row['leader_id']; ?>" name="selected[]" onChange="myFunction(this)" class="<?php echo $row['state_point'];?>">
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><span class="subdetails"><?php echo $i++; ?></span></td>
                  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left"><span class="subdetails"><?php echo $row['leader_name']; ?></span></td>
                  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left"><?php echo $row['facebook']; ?></td>
                  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left"><?php echo $row['twitter']; ?></td>
                  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left" class="<?php echo $row['state_point'];?>" ><?php echo $row['state_point'];?>



     </td>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href='#'><img style='vertical-align:bottom;' src='images/view profile.png' width='10' height='10' border='0'></td>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="radio" name="pm" value="pm"></td>
                </tr>

    <?php  } ?>
    <tr>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Remaining Budget : </td>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span id="total" class="0">1000</span></td>
                  <td>
                  </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="submit" name="add"  value="Add Team"> </td>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="reset"  value="Clear Team" onClick="javascript:changeTextToBlack();"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
    </form>
```

this is my table code, i want to make changes in 
it automatically changes value to local , federal in place of state when selecting a dropdown list, other fields remain same as it is, only change in **value column**

Comment: please post your code here...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. Using JavaScript/Ajax and HTML:

```
<select id="text" name="hub" onChange="refine_search();">
    <option value="test1">test1</test1>
    <option value="test2">test2</test2>
    <option value="test3">test3</test3>
</select>
```

Now JavaScript Code for **`refine_search()`** function:

```
function refine_search(x)
{
    var temp_test=document.getElementById('test');
    test=temp_test.options[temp_test.selectedIndex].value;

    /*Copy this entire code from here this is an AJAX Call*/
    var xmlHttp;
    try{    
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    }catch (e){
        try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
        }catch (e){
            try{
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e){
                alert("No AJAX!?");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    var url="www.google.com";// url which contains the next server side page to query
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if ( this.readyState == 4 ) //when the page responds back
        {
            //change to this page.
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send(null); 
}
```

This will do the needful

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<select id="text" name="sel" onChange="reloadPage();">
        <option value="a" <? echo ($_GET['sel'] == 'a' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?> >test1</test1>
        <option value="b" <? echo ($_GET['sel'] == 'b' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>>test2</test2>

    </select>
```

and add this

```
function reloadPage()
{
    document.frm_change.method = 'get';
    document.frm_change.submit();
}
```

when form will submit the sel option value will auto selected, no need of AJAX.